# multipart/form-data not working in pytest error :404

Tags: multipartform-data

```
def test_post_data():
    data={"title":"asda",
          "body":"asdcasd",
          "tags":["asd"]
          }
    url = open("/home/hitesh/Downloads/download.jpeg", "rb")
    thumbnail = open("/home/hitesh/Downloads/download.jpeg", "rb")
    headers = {'Content-type':'multipart/form-data'}
    response = client.post("/blog_post/?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhIiwiZXhwIjoxNjgxNDU2Mzc0fQ.J9xWZiUit6wuamDSFYVvFjpt7gGcdYH2NJVLc9l2kxM",files={"data":data,"file1name":url,"file2name":thumbnail},headers=headers)
    print(response)
    assert response.status_code == 200,f"{response.content}"
```

while i am running this code i am getting error:404 not found details

what i can do for make this code run